# How to get Excel data from OneDrive using JavaScript and display in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, excel, onedrive

I am trying to get data from an Excel file saved on OneDrive using JavaScript embedded in a SharePoint page.

I just need the reading operation for creating a chart using JSCanvas.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Thank you very much.